# Reversing a summation algorithum

Tags: algorithms

I have a bit of a math problem on a hobby project of mine, and I was hoping some of the experts here could give me some guidance.

I am preforming some calculations on a set of numbers where the following is true with any given value for w, where:

[image: ∑▒C_n/(∑▒〖C_n/S_n +w/100〗) =t]

For example:

Given the set [{C=100,S=47.9},{C=50,S=28.0}], and w=100

[image: [100/([100/47.9]+[50/28.0]+(100/100) )]+[50/([100/47.9]+[50/28.0]+(100/100) )]=30.7794]

Except now what I need to do is find w for any given value of t. I know I need to solve for w in the equation somehow, and then it should be simple enough to convert it to code for my algorithm. Unfortunately I am having a bit of trouble with the math involved. I know I did these before in calc, but I can't quite remember it.

Would anyone be able to show me how I would go about solving this problem?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The thing to notice though is that denominator is the same in each term, so it can be factored out ofthe sum. A little rearranging of the terms will then get w one side and t, the sum of all the cn and the sum of cn/sn on the other.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a solution to a math problem, and one of interest only to the OP.


Comment: This question might be better suited for math.SE. I have flagged it for migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually just algebra, no calculus involved.  The trick is that the denominator is constant, so you can factor it out.

```
Sum(Cn) = t(Sum(Cn/Sn) + w/100)
Sum(Cn)/t = Sum(Cn/Sn) + w/100
100 * (Sum(Cn)/t - Sum(Cn/Sn)) = w
```

Comment: You are absolutely right! It looks so much easier when you put it like that. Many thanks! :)